# Excel wildcards and dates

Tags: excel, wildcard

I'm creating a countifs statement and reached a head scratching point.

```
=COUNTIFS(
'IR-RPI Data'!$B:$B,$A3,
'IR-RPI Data'!$D:$D,"04" & "/" & G2 & "/" & "20" & "19")
```

If I change any of the last line to wildcards the formula breaks. G2 refers to a cell with data "09".

I want the last line to read...

```
'IR-RPI Data'!$D:$D,"*" & G2 & "*")
```

...but I'm getting errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanx for looking,

Sam

EDIT:

[image: Data]
[image: Results]
I would like this formula...

```
=COUNTIFS(
'IR-RPI Data'!$B:$B,$A3,
'IR-RPI Data'!$D:$D,"04" & "/" & G2 & "/" & "20" & "19")
```

to work in the B3 (second picture)

I hope this rambling mess makes sense to someone.

Thanx again,

Sam

Comment: Important note: dates are not text. Not sure why you need to concatenate here, unless you're dealing with *text-that-looks-like-dates*.

Comment: My dates are set as dd-mmm-yy which displays 03/09/2019. I'm trying to check how many X are in a particular date.

Comment: Dates are just numbers, not text. Change the format to General  - is the cell a number?

Comment: Thanx Ben, you are correct. How would one keep the text in general rather than numbers?

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Can you explain what you're trying to COUNTIFS? What criteria?

Comment: I'm checking names against certain strings for certain dates... i.e. B:B contains names and A3 refers to a specific name. D:D contains dates and G2 a specific date.

Comment: Maybe [edit] your question with some sample data and the expected result, so we can better understand your question.

Comment: Thanx for your help BigBen. Used =COUNTIFS(
'IR-RPI Data'!$B:$B, $A3,
'IR-RPI Data'!$E:$E, "<"&H2,
'IR-RPI Data'!$F:$F, G$1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates aren't text, but numbers. Use `DATE` within your `COUNTIFS` to create a true date. As an example:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$5,$A10,$E$1:$E$5,$B$8,$D$1:$D$5,">="&DATE(2019,B$9,1),$D$1:$D$5,"<="&EOMONTH(DATE(2019,B$9,1),0))
```

[image]